# Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type long

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators, boolean-logic

I am doing some conversion of some old VB code to C#. I am getting this error when converting a couple of properties.

"Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type long"

This is what the VB code looks like and hoping for some help with this.

```
Public Property Value() As Integer
    Get
        If (Me.m_Value < 32768) Then
            Return Me.m_Value
        Else
            Return -32768 + (Me.m_Value - 32768)
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal PLCValue As Integer)
        Me.m_Value = PLCValue
    End Set
End Property

Public Property B0() As Boolean
    Get
        If ((Me.m_Value And &H1&) = &H1&) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal State As Boolean)
        If (State = True) Then
            Me.m_Value = Me.m_Value Or &H1&
        Else
            Me.m_Value = Me.m_Value And (Not &H1&)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
Public Property B1() As Boolean
    Get
        If ((Me.m_Value And &H2&) = &H2&) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal State As Boolean)
        If (State = True) Then
            Me.m_Value = Me.m_Value Or &H2&
        Else
            Me.m_Value = Me.m_Value And (Not &H2&)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

This is what it looks like when converting it. Both set conditions is where I am getting this error. The Or | I can change to casting to (int) and the error goes away but not sure on the else condition how to adjust that?

```
public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_value < 32768))
            {
                return _value;
            }
            else
            {
                return -32768 + (_value - 32768);
            }
        }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public bool B0
    {
        get
        {
            if (((_value & 0x1L) == 0x1L))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value == true))
            {
                _value = _value | 0x1L;
            }
            else
            {                    
                _value = _value & (!0x1L); 
            }
        }
    }
    public bool B1
    {
        get
        {
            if (((_value & 0x2L) == 0x2L))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value == true))
            {
                _value = _value | 0x2L;
            }
            else
            {
                _value = _value & (!0x2L);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: This converter is doing weird stuff, the `Not` on the integer value should have been interpreted as a bitwise negate, for which `~` is the right operator.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt: you should write this as the answer - this is absolutely correct.

Comment: Check the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4.aspx, the part with: For numeric expressions...

Comment: That looks like it was it! I did look at what you stated but obviously I did not put 2 & 2 together! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Complete code, hopefully correct:

```
public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_value < 32768))
            {
                return _value;
            }
            else
            {
                return -32768 + (_value - 32768);
            }
        }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public bool B0
    {
        get
        {
            if (((_value & 0x1) == 0x1))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value == true))
            {
                _value = _value | 0x1;
            }
            else
            {                    
                _value = _value & (~0x1); 
            }
        }
    }
    public bool B1
    {
        get
        {
            if (((_value & 0x2) == 0x2))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value == true))
            {
                _value = _value | 0x2;
            }
            else
            {
                _value = _value & (~0x2);
            }
        }
    }
```

As I pointed out in my comment and was confirmed by @mataps link, the `Not` on the numerical value should be interpreted as a bitwise negate `~` in C#. Also, I dropped the `L` literal everywhere, because `Value` is of type `int`, not `long`, so now the compiler hopefully doesn't compain about doing bitwise operations on different types (`int` and `long`)